# nodejs upload 2 single image in 2 different folder

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to upload 2 images in different folder but got errors. I have use array for multer but still shows unexpected field or filename. I have use node as a server using multer

my code is

```
const DIR = './fabric/img/';
const designDIR = './fabric/design/';
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

 destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
    cb(null, fileName)
  }
});
const designstorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, designDIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
    cb(null, fileName)
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  designstorage: designstorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
      return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
    }
  }
});

router.post('/fabric', upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {


  const io = req.app.get('io');
  const product = new db.fabric({
    image: req.protocol + "://" + req.hostname + ":" + req.socket.localPort + "/img/" + req.files.filename,
    design: req.protocol + "://" + req.hostname + ":" + req.socket.localPort + "/design/" + req.files.filename,

  });

  product.save().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "product added successfully!",
      productCreated: {
        image: result.image,
        design: result.design
      }
    })
    io.emit('productAdded');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err),
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
  })
})
```

got following error when post from postman "image": "http://localhost:3000/img/undefined"

Comment: Try `req.files.filename` instead of `req.file.filename`. Notice the `s`. `Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined` means `file` is undefined.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette tried that too but got http://localhost:3000/img/undefined

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette able to post image but got filename undefined

Comment: `req.files` is an array. So try iterate the array... Or if you are sure there is alway 2 files, use `req.files[0].filename` and `req.files[1].filename`.

Answer (score 0):

try with req.files[0].originalname, req.files[1].originalname,
if not check with console then you will get the required fieldname